# PHP function($param1)($_REQUEST, $e){...} what's the second parentheses, where to read?

Tags: php

Met a function call of the form:

```
$response = controller($activePage)($_REQUEST);
```

and the function itself of the form:

```
function controller(string $name) {......}
```

question: Where can you read - what the second brackets mean.

In the PHP documentation, function arguments are enclosed in single parentheses

Comment: `controller` returns a function and that function is called with second parentheses.

Comment: It's equivalent to `$f = controller($activePage); $f()`…

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is a function call to:

```
controller($activePage)
```

This call **returns a function**, that takes as an argument `$_REQUEST` and is executed in turn.

E.g.

```
function controller(string $name): callable
{
    return function ($param) {
        var_dump($param); // show contents of $_REQUEST
    };
}
```

Note: for more on [callbacks](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php)

Working [demo](https://3v4l.org/B9pne)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the `controller` function returns back a `closure` *(aka: anonymous [functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php))* function, which means that the second parentheses are the call of the closure.

The simplification of this code: `$response = controller($activePage)($_REQUEST);` is this:

```
$callback = controller($activePage);
$response = $callback($_REQUEST);
```

The `controller` could look like that inside:

```
function controller($page) {
    return function($request) {
       // Do some work here
       // ...
       // and return something

       return $result;
    }
}
```

Finally, based on the documentation related to anonymous functions, if you need to use some variables coming from the parent function body, you could use the `use` like that:

```
function controller($page) {
    $page = str_replace('something', 'i-do-a-test', $page);
    
    return function($request) use ($page) {
       $result = 'my-slug-' . $page;
       // Do some work here
       // ...
       // and return something

       return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I did not find it in the documentation, I was just guessing ..

Comment: then, following the logic, you can write ?: <br /> controller($activePage)($_REQUEST); function controller($activePage) {
    return function($request)($param) {
       // Do some work here
       // ...
       // and return something
       return  function($param){...};
    }
}

Comment: Yes, if you want to implement your own controller function that returns a closure, and then you can execute your closure you can do it this way.

Also please keep in mind, that if you got the answer you are looking for, don't forget to upvote the right answers, as well to check the correct one using the checkmark below the voting buttons :)